# How to find specific word followed by number in a dataframe using Python

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe which contains a series of patterns.

Example dataframe:

```
mydata: 
[ 'Ticket number INS 00909',
'Ticket number INS00909',
'Ticket number REQ 8776',
'Ticket number REQ#8777',
'Ticket number REQ #8778',
'Ticket number REQ8778',
'Number is CR 0098445554',
'No INS number',
'No REQUEST',
'DESCRIBED']

Search_Values = ['INS', 'REQ', 'CR' ]
pattern = '|'.join(Search_Values)
df['check'] = df['mydata'].str.contains(pattern)
```

Basically, I want to find and extract only the ticket numbers. What logic should be applied to pull the CR, REQ , INS followed by number? Sometimes the string would contain special characters like  #, -, :, *, space(\s) in between Req and number.Can anyone please help?

Comment: Which is your desired output? A list of numbers all together? A dictionary as `{'type of ticket': list of ticket numbers}`? A new dataframe column with a string `'type of ticket - ticket number'`?

Comment: @Andrea Blengino: I want the entire ticket number in a new dataframe column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have to distinguish between `INS`, `RES` and `CR` numbers, you can use this code:

```
import re

data = [ 'Ticket number INS 00909',
'Ticket number INS00909',
'Ticket number REQ 8776',
'Ticket number REQ#8777',
'Ticket number REQ #8778',
'Ticket number REQ8778',
'Number is CR 0098445554',
'No INS number',
'No REQUEST',
'DESCRIBED']

numbers = []

for item in data:
    res = re.findall(r'[0-9]+$', item)
    if res != []:
        numbers.append(res[0])

print(numbers)
```

which gives a simple list with all the ticket numbers  together:

```
['00909', '00909', '8776', '8777', '8778', '8778', '0098445554']
```

---

Otherwise, if you need to distinguish the ticket types, use this:

```
import re

data = [ 'Ticket number INS 00909',
'Ticket number INS00909',
'Ticket number REQ 8776',
'Ticket number REQ#8777',
'Ticket number REQ #8778',
'Ticket number REQ8778',
'Number is CR 0098445554',
'No INS number',
'No REQUEST',
'DESCRIBED']

numbers = {'INS': [], 'REQ': [], 'CR': []}

for item in data:
    res = re.findall(r'[0-9]+$', item)
    if res != []:
        if 'INS' in item:
            numbers['INS'].append(res[0])
        elif 'REQ' in item:
            numbers['REQ'].append(res[0])
        elif 'CR' in item:
            numbers['CR'].append(res[0])

print(numbers)
```

which gives a dictionary with a key for each ticket type:

```
{'INS': ['00909', '00909'], 'REQ': ['8776', '8777', '8778', '8778'], 'CR': ['0098445554']}
```

---

I kept the ticket numbers as `str` and I had not converted them into `int` in order to avoid this, perhaps unwanted, conversion: `'00909' ---> 909`.
This solution is based on the assumption that the ticket number is always at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a new df column. The indices of the mydata strings are used to take slices with only your desired info. The last if/else block checks to see if there are numbers in the string to avoid appending false positive matches.

```
order_list = []

for idx, row in df.iterrows():

    if 'INS' in row['mydata']:
        index = row['mydata'].index('INS')
    elif  'REQ' in row['mydata']:
        index = row['mydata'].index('REQ')
    elif  'CR' in row['mydata']:
        index = row['mydata'].index('CR')


    if any(map(str.isdigit, row['mydata'])):
        order_list.append(row['mydata'][index:])
    else:
        order_list.append('')

df['order'] = order_list

print(df)

    mydata                  order
0   Ticket number INS 00909 INS 00909
1   Ticket number INS00909  INS00909
2   Ticket number REQ 8776  REQ 8776
3   Ticket number REQ#8777  REQ#8777
4   Ticket number REQ #8778 REQ #8778
5   Ticket number REQ8778   REQ8778
6   Number is CR 0098445554 CR 0098445554
7   No INS number   
8   No REQUEST  
9   DESCRIBED
```